# Line number: Any way to use __LINE__ to return line number of input file?

Tags: c++, c

New to C/C++/C#. Is there any way to use `__LINE__` to return the current line number of the **input file** read through stdio.h (e.g., getchar())? If not, is there another better way to do it?

Comment: No. `__LINE__` is evaluated at compile-time, not run-time.

Comment: BTW, C, C++, C# are three different languages. Choose one of them, and give the standard you are interested in, e.g. [C++11](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11)

Answer (score 8):

No, `__LINE__` has nothing to do with the standard input. It is just macro-expanded by the compiler (to the line number inside the source code file).

If you need to count the lines of the standard input, read it line by line with [getline(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getline.3.html) or [std::getline](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) and friends in C++ ...

Don't use `fgets` or the old and dead `gets`

Answer (score 1):

`__LINE__` is a special C/C++ Preprocessor define that is translated to the source code file line number of the current line in the source code file that is being processed.  It has nothing to do with any kind of input or output from the actual C/C++ program.

`__LINE__` along with another special C/C++ Preprocessor define of `__FILE__` is often used when generating logs to provide the source code file name (which is what `__FILE__` is defined as) and the specific line number (which is what `__LINE__` is defined as).

So there may be a log function, whose interface looks like `log (char *pszMessage, char *pszFile, int iLineNo)` and you could use it something like `log ("My Log message", __FILE__, __LINE__);`

These are special built-in defines whose values are changed by the Preprocessor as it opens and processes a source file.

As mentioned by Basile Starynkevitch, if you want to count lines you will need to use one of the C/C++ input functions/objects to read lines and count them as you read them.